# How to copy a website from one computer to another?

Tags: asp.net, web, copy

I have a website which was created using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.

I want to copy the website onto a CD so that my professor can run it on his computer.

However, since Visual Studio creates the solution of the website in My Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects, I cannot simply copy the website folder only.

What is the best way to transfer a copy of this website please?  Thank you and all the best for the new year.

Comment: Do you mean that you don't want to give him the source code?

Comment: No, I want to give him the source code as well.  I want to copy the project in its entirety so that my professor can open it on his computer and view the source code as well as run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can copy the folder. It will make the website in a folder within `projects` and you will be able to copy this folder onto a CD. When you run the website you can see where it is stored, if you look into the address bar of your web browser it will say something like `c:\Users\You\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MyWebsite\index.html`. In this case the folder you need to copy is `c:\Users\You\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MyWebsite\` - instruct your professor to open the folder and select `index.html`.

The question is, have you used something other than just HTML and CSS to do this? Its probably a stupid question as if you have used ASP or similar to create the website you would probably also have the knowledge to copy said website. In the off chance that you HAVE used ASP or similar you will need to put this website onto a server that runs ASP.

However, if you've just used Visual Studio to lay out the website and put in some content and such, then its most likely all the files are images, HTML and CSS which will happily run off a CD.

Comment: I have used ASP as the scripting language for this website.  This website is not going to be put online.  It's just an assignment that should run on a single computer only.

Comment: Hi Matthew. If the website is coded in ASP then it will have to be run from an ASP server unfortunately. Or you will have to pass the source code to your professor and let him build and run it in Visual Studio himself.

Comment: @Matthew clarification: when you say you have coded the site in ASP, do you really mean ASP, or ASP.NET?

Comment: The website is in ASP.NET.  Sorry for the lack of information on my part

Answer (score 0):

You have to search My Documents/Visual Studio 2010/WebSites/ 
And obviosly, u should find there the website of your solution. It is needed to copy the website folder and solution folder of your site from VS2010/Projects and /Websites folders to your professors' computer.

This way is right if your professor has VS 2010 installed.

Answer (score 0):

If your professor needs only to run it on his environment, you can use "Publish" feature of Visual Studio 2010 and choose the file system as the target.

Then burn the published folder.

He then will be able to copy it from the CD to his Microsoft.NET enabled application server and run it.

Answer (score -1):

Upload it to a cheap or free hosting provider and send the URL to your professor. If necessary, you can password-protect the site to prevent access by unauthorized third parties.

Comment: This wasn't the question. If the website is made of only HTML and CSS and Images then it will quite happily run from a CD.

Comment: To the contrary, the OP asked "How to copy a website from one computer to another?" and "What is the best way to transfer a copy of this website please?" The best way to transfer a website from one computer to another is via the web, just the way a website is intended to be served. Notwithstanding the OP's comment "I want to copy the website onto a CD," he asked us for the best answer. This is it.

Comment: Furthermore, see the OP's comment "I have used ASP" in response to your question.

Comment: Very well argued. Plus according to Matthew's comment on my answer it would appear he is using ASP which will have to run from a web server anyway. If you edit your question then I will be able to remove my downvote (I think that's how it works)

Comment: In most cases, you can simply click the down arrow again to remove your down vote.

Comment: Nah, when its been a while it won't let you remove it.